# Stop automatic comments in my crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have added the bellow cron jobs in my crontab :

```
0 5 * * * /bin/systemctl restart gb_subagent.service
28 13 * * * /home/comment.sh &>/tmp/errorcron.log
29 13 * * * bash /home/kill_slony_stop_sql.sh &>/tmp/errorcron.log
30 13 * * * /home/kill_brole_and_slonik.sh &>/tmp/errorcron.log
31 13 * * * /home/uncomment.sh &>/tmp/errorcron.log
```

And it seems that everytime they execute, many comment lines are added to the `crontab` :

```
\# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
\# (/var/tmp/cron installed on Mon Apr 13 09:03:58 2015)
\# (Cronie version 4.2)
\# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
\# (/var/tmp/cron installed on Mon Apr 13 09:00:57 2015)
\# (Cronie version 4.2)
```

How can I make them not add the comments, or maybe redirect them to a file?

Comment: anyone knows ? :(